# In a SQL group by statement, show one of the matching rows fields

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, group-by

I am trying to count entries in a table to identify records of interest.

I am grouping the results:

```
select code, count(1)
from data
group by code
order by count(1) desc
```

So, if I have several rows with the same code, the query will report the code with the count of how many times that code exists.

```
code | Count
123      3
321      2
231      1
```

from the table

```
code | title
123    firstcode
123    first code
123    The first code
321    The second code
321    The second code
231    The third code
```

I want to give an indication of what the code represents by displaying one (any (probably the first)) title field for one of the rows for each code.

How can I do this?

I feel I need to do something like:

```
select code, 
 ( select top 1 title from data d2 where d2.code = d.code
 ) title,
count(1)
from data d
group by ( select top 1 title from data d2 where d2.code = d.code
 ), code
order by count(1) desc
```

Comment: Which are you using, MySQL or SQL-Server? Please remove the other tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I often include the `min()` and `max()` when doing aggregations:

```
select code, count(1), min(title), max(title)
from data
group by code
order by count(1) desc
```